# Output to a csv file using Text::CSV_XS

Tags: perl, csv

I have a perl script which works fine printing to the screen but when I try to redirect the output to a csv file I get the following error: `Expected fields to an array ref`.  I am using `Text::CSV_XS` and the line that gives the error is `$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;`

```
#!/user/local/bin/perl
use Text::CSV_XS;
$|=1;

sub main {
    print "Enter file to process: ";
    my $file = <STDIN>;
    chomp $file;

    my @rows;
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
    open(INPUT, $file) or die("Input file $file not found.\n");
    while(my $line = <INPUT>) {
        if($line =~ /Assay/) {
            @words = split(" ",$line);
            push @rows, $words[1];
        }
        if($line =~/Date/) {
            @words = split(" ",$line);
            push @rows, $words[1];
            push @rows, $words[2];
        }
        if($line =~/Patient/) {
            @words = split(" ",$line);
            push @rows, $words[0];
            push @rows, $words[1];
            push @rows, $words[2];
        }
        if($line =~/channel_index/) {
            print $line;
        }

        if($line =~/Channel/) {
            @words = split(" ",$line);
            push @rows, $words[1];
            push @rows, $words[2];
        }
        if($line =~/DCMean/) {
            @words = split(" ",$line);
            push @rows, $words[0];
            push @rows, $words[1];
        }
    }

    $csv->eol ("\r\n");
    open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "new.csv" or die "new.csv: $!";
    $csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
    close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
    close(INPUT);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're pushing values onto `@rows`, you're just going to get one huge, flat array of scalars. That's probably not what you want.

Consider the following:

```
my @rows;
push @rows, 'a';
push @rows, 'b';
push @rows, 'c';
push @rows, 'd';
push @rows, 'e';
push @rows, 'f';
```

Gives us a flat array: `[a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

Where this:

```
my @rows;
push @rows, ['a', 'b', 'c'];
push @rows, ['d', 'e', 'f'];
```

Gives us a nested array: `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f]]`.

It also happens that arrays and arrayrefs are similar, but different. See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). This is a subtle concept, but crucial for advanced Perl development. Please read and understand it!

Your push code could look something like this:

```
push @rows, [$words[1], $words[2]];
```

The `[]` around those scalars creates an anonymous array reference. Since `@rows` will now be populated with array refs, you shouldn't need to change anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing error reporting line to following:

```
$csv->print ($fh, \@rows);
```

A quote from `Text::CSV_XS` CPAN documentation of `print` function

*It expects an array ref as input (not an array!)*